# What is Concurrent Session Control in Spring?

Tags: spring, session, spring-security

I was reading through Spring Security technical documentation for Concurrent Session Control. I understood that it is used to control access across multiple sessions from a single user. Can someone explain in more detail what exactly it does?

The details given in the tech documentation is too small to fully appreciate this. For example the documentation speaks of a way to direct user to an error page if she tries to log in the second time. This is not very obvious-why would it need to be an error? Intuitively it seems we need only **'warn'** the user of their second login and not to **'error'** them?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at SessionManagementConfigurer and its ConcurrencyControlConfigurer. You need to make a decision which behaviour match your application requirements.

For example you can decide to log out user from machine A if he log in to system from machine B (maxSessionsPreventsLogin method) and redirect user from machine A to specific url ( expiredUrl method ).